# Google Adwords API PHP - remove Oauth2 access for current access token

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I am successfully connecting to the Google Adwords API with the OAuth2 examples from Google. I want now to implement programatically the disconnection of the customer for this OAuth2 connection. 
I saw in some examples the function

```
$client->revokeToken()
```

but in my case this function is not present. I am using for the connection the libraries from

```
"googleads/googleads-php-lib": "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss-understand how Oauth2 works.   When you run your application a window pops up asking the user if they would like to grant your application permission to access their data.    Assuming the user says yes then your application can now access their data.  They are not logged in any scene.

What revoke does is remove the access that they granted to your application.

There is an issue about this on the issue forum [986](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/986)  I cant seem to figure out if the bug was fixed or not.

If you cant get it to work you can do

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

this works the same as the user removing your application from [Permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I understand the process of OAuth2. I tough theer is some function which is executing the call you send, thats why I am sking. It will be great if this can be a function, so I can handle it with my backend.

Comment: Ok, it works, as it returns a JSON empty object for success and some error for failure.

Comment: How can I refresh the access_token with the saved refresh_token?